# Filtering out value in list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to filter out last value in tuple in list of dictionaries. For example

```
X = [{'a': (123, 12445), 'b': (234, 34)}, {'a': (45666, 4), 'b': (3, 12)}]
```

to

```
Y = [{'a':  123, 'b': 234}, {'a': 45666, 'b': 3} ]
```

My attempt:

```
[{ j: i[j][0] } for j in i.keys() for i in result ]
```

But I get this:

```
[{'a': 123}, {'a': 45666}, {'b': 234}, {'b': 3}]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Dictionary comprehensions only work in Python 2.7+.  Since you are on Python 2.6, you can use [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html#func-dict) with a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> X = [{'a': (123, 12445), 'b': (234, 34)}, {'a': (45666, 4), 'b': (3, 12)}]
>>> [dict((k, v[0]) for k,v in x.iteritems()) for x in X]
[{'b': 234, 'a': 123}, {'b': 3, 'a': 45666}]
>>>
```

Comment: Either way, I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I am using python 2.6